# Compare two APIs response in Katalon Studio

Tags: katalon-studio

Can we compare two API's Responses in Katalon studio?

If possible, please provide me steps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you mean in comparing two API's responses? Compare some datas or just response status codes ? Also please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
 We can compare two APIs response and the difference will print in a file by using below code
//Required Packages
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper as JsonSlurper
import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils as CollectionUtils
import java.util.List as List`enter code here`
import java.lang.String as String
import java.io.FileWriter as FileWriter
import com.google.gson.*
import java.util.Date as Date
import java.util.*
import java.text.*

// Get response code and verify it

response1 = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('First API'))

WS.verifyResponseStatusCode(response1, 200)

response2 = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('Second API'))

WS.verifyResponseStatusCode(response2, 200)

def slurper = new JsonSlurper()

def result1 = slurper.parseText(response1.getResponseBodyContent())

println('1st Response is .....' + result1)

def result2 = slurper.parseText(response2.getResponseBodyContent())

println('2nd Response is .....' + result2)

if (!(result1.equals(result2))) {

ArrayList<String> listOne = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(result1))

ArrayList<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(result2))

listOne.removeAll(listTwo)

System.out.println('Additional Data of First Response' + listOne)

//Missing Data

listTwo.removeAll(listOne)

System.out.println('Missing Data of Second Response' + listTwo)

String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMddHHmm\'.json\'').format(new Date())

// Print the difference in a file( file name will be current time and date)

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter('D:\\APIResponseData\\' + fileName)

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()

String Additional = gson.toJson(listOne)

String Missing = gson.toJson(listTwo)

writer.write(('Additional Data.......' +Additional) + System.lineSeparator())

writer.write(('Missing Data......' + Missing) + System.lineSeparator())

writer.close()

 }

else{

println("Both APIs data same")

}
```